# How to delete HTML list items from two lists

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a list set up that throws two lists when content is put into a textbox, one list for a priority to-do list, and the other to delete unwanted content.

```js
function chapter05() {
  var uplist = document.getElementsByClassName('ch5')[0];

  btn_colors = {
    'hi': 'hiP',
    'med': 'medP',
    'low': 'lowP'
  }
  radios = document.getElementsByName('rgPrior');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      btn_selected_color = (btn_colors[radios[i].value]);
      break;
    }
  }

  var todo = document.getElementById('txtAdd').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  entry.className = btn_selected_color;
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
  uplist.appendChild(entry);

  var botlist = document.getElementsByClassName('ch5')[1];

  var todo = document.getElementById('txtAdd').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  var radio = document.createElement("input");
  radio.type = "radio";
  radio.name = radio;
  radio.value = radio;

  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete this item: " + todo + " "));
  entry.appendChild(radio);
  botlist.appendChild(entry);

  document.getElementById('txtAdd').value = " ";
}


function chapter05_del() {
}
```

```css
.hiP {
  color: red;
}

.medP {
  color: blue;
}

.lowP {
  color: green;
}

.ch5 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p style="">A to-do list</p>

<ol class="ch5"></ol>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
  <label for="txtAdd">New thing to do:</label>
  <input name="txtAdd" type="text" id="txtAdd" size="50" maxlength="50" />
</p>
<p>Set Priority</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="hi" id="rgPrior_0"/>High
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="med" id="rgPrior_1"/>Meduim
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="low" id="rgPrior_2"/>Low
  </label>
  <br/>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="Add a value" onClick="chapter05()" />
</p>
<br />

<p>Delete Items</p>

<ol class="ch5"></ol>

<p>
  <input type="button" name="btnDel" id="btnDel" value="Delete an item" onClick="chapter05_del()" />
</p>

</article>
```

The first button is to input the data onto the page (add content to the lists) the second is to delete content.

I have the first part working the way I want it, so that when something is put into the text area and a priority radio button is clicked, it adds to a generated list both in the to-do list and the delete list, and the delete list creates a radio button next to the item.

Now, what I've been trying to accomplish is that in the chapter05_del() function, if a radio button in the delete list of the chapter05() function is clicked, it removes the corresponding items from both the to-do list, and the delete list.

TL;DR Once the user has chosen the element to delete, remove them from both lists.

Comment: Did my solution worked for you?

Comment: It did, thank you! I apologize for the late response.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept/upvote the solution so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the updated code below. Comments in the code.

In `chapter05`, I have modified the below two lines to give a name and value to radio element created:

```
radio.name = "delete";
radio.value = todo;
```

```js
function chapter05() {
 var uplist = document.getElementsByClassName('ch5')[0];

 btn_colors = {
  'hi': 'hiP',
  'med': 'medP',
  'low': 'lowP'
 }
 radios = document.getElementsByName('rgPrior');

 for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
  if (radios[i].checked) {
   btn_selected_color = (btn_colors[radios[i].value]);
   break;
  }
 }

 var todo = document.getElementById('txtAdd').value;
 var entry = document.createElement('li');
 entry.className = btn_selected_color;
 entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo));
 uplist.appendChild(entry);

 var botlist = document.getElementsByClassName('ch5')[1];

 var todo = document.getElementById('txtAdd').value;
 var entry = document.createElement('li');
 var radio = document.createElement("input");
 radio.type = "radio";
 radio.name = "delete";
 radio.value = todo;

 entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete this item: " + todo + " "));
 entry.appendChild(radio);
 botlist.appendChild(entry);

 document.getElementById('txtAdd').value = " ";
}

function chapter05_del() {
 var botlist = document.querySelectorAll('.ch5')[1];
 var li = botlist.querySelectorAll("li input[type='radio']:checked");
 
 if (li.length > 0) { //If user selected a radio button
  var valToDelete = li[0].value; //Get radion button value
  li[0].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(li[0].parentNode); //Remove the todo item from delete list

  var toplist = document.querySelectorAll('.ch5')[0]; //Get handle to top to-do 
  //Get handle to all li and loop
  [].slice.call(toplist.querySelectorAll("li")).map(function (el){
     if (el.innerText.trim() === valToDelete.trim()) el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }) 
 }
}
```

```css
.hiP {
 color: red;
}

.medP {
 color: blue;
}

.lowP {
 color: green;
}

.ch5 {
 padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p style="">A to-do list</p>

<ol class="ch5"></ol>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
 <label for="txtAdd">New thing to do:</label>
 <input name="txtAdd" type="text" id="txtAdd" size="50" maxlength="50" />
</p>
<p>Set Priority</p>
<p>
 <label>
<input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="hi" id="rgPrior_0"/>High
</label>
 <br/>
 <label>
<input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="med" id="rgPrior_1"/>Meduim
</label>
 <br/>
 <label>
<input type="radio" name="rgPrior" value="low" id="rgPrior_2"/>Low
</label>
 <br/>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
 <input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" value="Add a value" onClick="chapter05()" />
</p>
<br />

<p>Delete Items</p>
<ol class="ch5"></ol>
<p>
 <input type="button" name="btnDel" id="btnDel" value="Delete an item" onClick="chapter05_del()" />
</p>
```